# Why do I get this error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm write this query:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center
   SELECT code_markaz, name_markaz  
   FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP ti
                     WHERE ti.code_markaz = Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center.code_markaz);
```

but when I run that query I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   The multi-part identifier "Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center.code_markaz" could not be bound.

What happened? How can I solve that?

Comment: because you not define this table `Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center` in `FROM`

Comment: You have mentioned Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP table at both the FROM clause. You need to mention Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center table at one place

Comment: @tinka please write correct query and post to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's happening with the answers, but I would assume you want to insert the rows that don't exist in the table (field code_markaz) and that you can do this way:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center (code_markaz, name_markaz)
SELECT code_markaz, name_markaz  
FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center c
      WHERE c.code_markaz = tmp.code_markaz)
```

I also added the columns in the insert statement. If there's only 2 columns in the table it will work without them.

Answer (score -1):

The table being inserted into (`Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center`) does not have a column called `code_markaz`.

Name the target columns:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center (some_col_1, some_col_2)
   SELECT code_markaz, name_markaz  
   FROM ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The error comes due to `Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center` table not reference in you not exist inner query.

As above suggested you have to give either alias or join that table.

```
...FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP t
   JOIN Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_Center ccdac
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TEMP ti
        WHERE ti.code_markaz = CCDAC.code_markaz);
```

Comment: get this errror:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.

Comment: This has errors. You have to tell what columns to join `ON`.

Comment: @samyi how can i tell that?

Comment: You cannot go from `JOIN` to `NOT EXISTS`... it's syntactically incorrect.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: You can use any join based on your requirement to insert, while not exist just ignore the result set.  Also @Sam yi, in your link where is written that you will not used both this in a statement.

Comment: Hi. I'm not saying you can't use both. You never completed your JOIN clause because it's missing `ON`. Also, when you're writing correlated subqueries, you have to use a `WHERE` clause before `NOT EXISTS`.